# Puppet: Access hashkey in dynamic variable path

Tags: puppet

I've got a puppet hash type data structure like this to store ssh keys:

```
class users::sshkeys {
  $user1 = {
      user1 => {
          key => 'AAAAAA',
          type => 'ssh-rsa'
       }
  }
  $user2 = {
      user2 => {
          key => 'BBBBBB',
          type => 'ed25519'
      }
  }
}
```

I can access a key like this:

```
$users::sshkeys::user1['user1']['key']
```

I would like to access a key dynamically (e.g. in a loop), like this:

```
$users = ['user1', 'user2']

$users.each |$user| {
  $users::sshkeys::$user[$user]['key']
}
```

I found a solution to access a dynamic class/variable like this:

```
$mydynamicvar = getvar("users::sshkeys::${user1}")
notify{"$mydynamicvar":}
```

This seems to return a String, so that  I can't access the hashkeys inside:

```
notify{"$mydynamicuser[$user]['key']":}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Instead of separates hashes, you should merge them into one hash and retain the same structure within the hash. That will make the rest of this much easier for you, since you iterate on one hash and can iterate over it without assuming keys beforehand like you are currently doing.

Comment: ... and that would not be any harder or even very much different to implement, yet it would offer you more possibilities, such as moving the data into Hiera.

Comment: Thanks for your Tip, I'll try that later. I already had groups before like
$sysadmins = {
   user1 => {
      key => ...
   }
    user2 => {
      ...
}

By having every user hash in a single variable I thought I might gain some flexibility by summarizing them in groups like this (but haven't tried to parse that yet..):
$sysadmins = "
  $user1
  $user2
"
If I have one big hash, is there a chance to form groups from the keys/users in that hash later?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it :) Putting all hashes into one variable (here: $all_users) and summarizing them into groups works like this:

```
$sysadmins = { 
  user1 => $all_users['user1'],
  user2 => $all_users['user2']
}
```

Thanks for pointing me to the right direction @MattSchuchard

With a big hash even receiving ssh key and key type in a loop works:

```
 $users = ['user1', 'user2']

  $users.each |$user| {
    profiles::users::sshkeys { $user:
      user                    => $user,
      group                   => 'sftpusers',
      ssh_authorized_key      => $users::sshkeys::all_keys::all_users[$user]['key'],
      ssh_authorized_key_type => $users::sshkeys::all_keys::all_users[$user]['type'],
      shell                   => $shell,
      }
    }
```